# how i can add a text on pdf?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I found some code to show PDF file and, the code has a pencil to draw on pdf but I want to change the pencil to text. When I click on button I can write a text and move the text anywhere on view

I want to add text and change the size and move it as I want.

[image]

```
    //
//  ViewController.swift
//  PDFTest
//
//  Created by Prashoor Chitnis on 22/11/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 InfoBeans LLC. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import PDFKit

struct PAIRAnn {
    var drawing: PDFAnnotation;
    var button: PDFAnnotation;
    var currentPage: PDFPage;
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, PDFViewDelegate, DrawEventListener {

    @IBOutlet weak var closeBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var undoBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var pencil: UIBarButtonItem!

    var selectedAnnotation = [PAIRAnn]()

    var position: CGPoint?
    var currentPage : PDFPage?

    var pView: PDFView?
    var pdfView : PDFView {
        get {
            if pView == nil {
                pView =  PDFView(frame: self.view.frame)
                pView?.delegate = self
            }
            return pView!
        }
    }

    var fadeView: UIView?
    var messageView : UIView {
        get {
            if fadeView == nil {
                fadeView =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: (self.view.frame.size.width - 300)/2, y: 30, width: 300, height: 55))
                var frm = (fadeView?.bounds)!
                frm.origin.y = 15
                frm.size.height = 25
                let text = UILabel(frame: frm)
                text.textAlignment = .center
                text.text = "Double-Click on any spot to begin"
                text.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
                fadeView?.addSubview(text)
                fadeView?.layer.cornerRadius = 27.5
                fadeView?.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
                fadeView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
            }
            return fadeView!
        }
    }

    var drawVw: DrawScreen?
    var drawView : DrawScreen {
        get {
            if drawVw == nil {
                drawVw =  DrawScreen(frame: self.view.frame)
                drawVw?.listener = self
            }
            return drawVw!
        }
    }

    private var gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer?
    private var gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
        get {
            if gesture == nil {
                gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(addDrawing(sender:)))
                gesture?.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
            }
            return gesture!
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.closeBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.saveBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.undoBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.pencil.isEnabled = true
        self.view.insertSubview(self.pdfView, at: 0)
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "EN8", withExtension: "pdf")
        self.pdfView.document = PDFDocument.init(url: url!)
    }

    @IBAction func addPencil(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.pencil.isEnabled = false
        self.view.insertSubview(self.messageView, aboveSubview: self.pdfView)
        self.pdfView.addGestureRecognizer(self.gestureRecognizer)
    }

    func removeMessage() {
        if self.messageView.superview == nil {
            return
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            self.messageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 0, y: -70)
        }) { (success) in
            self.messageView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.messageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }

    @objc func addDrawing(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.removeMessage()
        self.position = sender.location(in: self.view)
        self.view.insertSubview(self.drawView, at: 1)
        currentPage = self.pdfView.currentPage
        self.pdfView.go(to: currentPage!)

        self.pencil.isEnabled = false
        self.undoBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.saveBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.closeBtn.isEnabled = true
    }

    func pdfViewWillClick(onLink sender: PDFView, with url: URL) {

        var checkVal = url.absoluteString
        checkVal = checkVal.replacingOccurrences(of: "path://", with: "")
        var draw: PDFAnnotation?
        for ann in self.allLinks() {
            let value = "\(ann.value(forAnnotationKey: PDFAnnotationKey(rawValue: "Link"))!)"
            if  checkVal == value {
                draw = ann
                break
            }
        }
        var currpage: PDFPage? = nil
        var button: PDFAnnotation?
        for (btn, page) in self.allButtons() {
            let value = "\(btn.value(forAnnotationKey: PDFAnnotationKey(rawValue: "_Path"))!)"
            if  checkVal == value {
                currpage = page
                button = btn
                break
            }
        }

        if draw != nil && button != nil && currpage != nil {
            let color = draw?.value(forAnnotationKey: PDFAnnotationKey(rawValue: "_Color")) as! String
            switch (color) {
            case "red":
                draw?.color = UIColor.red
                break
            default:
                break
            }
            currpage?.removeAnnotation(button!)

            self.editButtonItem.isEnabled = false
            self.undoBtn.isEnabled = true
           self.pencil.isEnabled = false
            self.selectedAnnotation.append(PAIRAnn.init(drawing: draw!, button: button!, currentPage: currpage!))
        }
    }

    @IBAction func undoAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.removeMessage()
        if self.selectedAnnotation.count > 0 {
            for pairs in self.selectedAnnotation {
                pairs.drawing.color = UIColor.clear
                pairs.currentPage.addAnnotation(pairs.button)
            }
            self.selectedAnnotation = []
            self.closeBtn.isEnabled = false
            self.saveBtn.isEnabled = false
            self.undoBtn.isEnabled = false
            self.pencil.isEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            self.drawView.undo()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func removeDrawing(sender: Any) {
        self.removeMessage()
        self.pdfView.removeGestureRecognizer(self.gestureRecognizer)
        self.drawView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.closeBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.saveBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.undoBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.pencil.isEnabled = true
    }

    func drawDidBegin() {
        self.undoBtn.isEnabled = true
        self.saveBtn.isEnabled = true
    }

    func drawingGotEmpty() {
        self.undoBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.saveBtn.isEnabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func saveDrawing(_ sender: Any) {
        self.pdfView.removeGestureRecognizer(self.gestureRecognizer)
        self.currentPage = self.pdfView.page(for: self.drawView.touches[0].path.first!, nearest: true)
        var arrayPath = [UIBezierPath]()
        for touches in self.drawView.touches {
            let bPth = UIBezierPath.init()
            let point = self.pdfView.convert(touches.path.first!, to: self.currentPage!)
            bPth.move(to: point)
            if touches.path.count > 1 {
                for i in 1...touches.path.count-1 {
                    let tch = self.pdfView.convert(touches.path[i], to: self.currentPage!)
                    bPth.addLine(to: tch)
                }
            }
            arrayPath.append(bPth)
        }
        let ann = PDFAnnotation.init(bounds: (self.currentPage?.bounds(for: self.pdfView.displayBox))!, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.ink, withProperties: nil)
        ann.shouldDisplay = false
        for bPth in arrayPath {
            ann.add(bPth)
        }

        ann.color = UIColor.clear
        let stamp = "PAGE_\(Date.init().timeIntervalSince1970)"
        ann.setValue(stamp, forAnnotationKey: PDFAnnotationKey.init(rawValue: "Link"))
        ann.setValue("red", forAnnotationKey: PDFAnnotationKey.init(rawValue: "_Color"))
        self.currentPage?.addAnnotation(ann)

        let linkPoint = self.pdfView.convert(self.position!, to: self.currentPage!)
        let linkAnn = PDFAnnotation.init(bounds: CGRect(x: linkPoint.x - 20, y: linkPoint.y - 12, width: 40, height: 24), forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.widget, withProperties: nil)
        linkAnn.widgetFieldType = .button
        linkAnn.widgetDefaultStringValue = "Open"
        linkAnn.widgetControlType = .pushButtonControl
        linkAnn.action = PDFActionURL(url: URL(string: "path://\(stamp)")!)
        linkAnn.setValue(stamp, forAnnotationKey: PDFAnnotationKey.init(rawValue: "_Path"))
        linkAnn.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        self.currentPage?.addAnnotation(linkAnn)

        self.drawView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.closeBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.saveBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.undoBtn.isEnabled = false
        self.pencil.isEnabled = true
    }

    func allButtons() -> [(PDFAnnotation,PDFPage)]{
        var list = [(PDFAnnotation,PDFPage)]()
        let checkType = PDFAnnotationSubtype.widget.rawValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "");
        for page in self.pdfView.visiblePages() {
            for ann in page.annotations {
                if ann.type! ==  checkType && ann.widgetFieldType == .button {
                    list.append((ann, page))
                }
            }
        }
        return list
    }

    func allLinks() -> [PDFAnnotation]{
        var list = [PDFAnnotation]()
        let checkType = PDFAnnotationSubtype.ink.rawValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "");
        for page in self.pdfView.visiblePages() {
            for ann in page.annotations {
                if ann.type! ==  checkType {
                    list.append(ann)
                }
            }
        }
        return list
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did u find answer for this ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 no , not yet

Comment: Have you find answer?